# How to create a list of lists in PHP?

Tags: php

This might be basic question but how do I create a list of lists in PHP. I would like to perform the following operations:

```
var x = List(List(1,1,1),List(2,2,2), List(3,3))
echo x[0]   //prints List(1,1,1)
echo x[1]   //prints List(2,2,2)
x  = x.List(4,4,4)
echo x      //prints List(List(1,1,1),List(2,2,2), List(3,3),List(4,4,4))
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for all helpful answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a list of lists using arrays.

```
$list1 = array(array('some stuff','more stuff'),array('more stuff2','some more'));
```

Or something like so:

```
$sub_list1=array('some stuff','more stuff');
$sub_list2=array('more stuff2','some more');
$list1 = array($sub_list1,$sub_list2);
```

You could access these lists like so:

```
echo $list1[0][1]; // Outputs "more stuff"
echo $list1[1][0]; // Outputs "more stuff2"
               ^ Select the element in that sub list
            ^ Select the sub list
```

Answer (score 6):

Lists are called "arrays" in PHP and they're pretty easy to work with:

You can instantiate one just by specifying its members:

```
$x = array(
    array(1, 1, 1),
    array(2, 2, 2),
    array(3, 3)
);
```

To append to an array, use empty square brackets:

```
$x[] = array(4, 4, 4);
```

To access a particular member, give its key in square brackets:

```
$x[0];  // array(1, 1, 1)
```

This works for multidimensional arrays too:

```
$x[0][2];  // 1
```

To print out an array so you can see the contents, use `print_r` or `var_dump` .. though `print_r` is neater for arrays.

```
echo $x;  // "Array" .. not great

print_r($x);
/* something like this:
array(
    0 => array (
        0 => 1
        1 => 1
        2 => 1
    )
    1 => array (
.. etc
*/
```

Arrays can also use strings as the key:

```
$x['foo'] = 'bar';
```

These are called "associative arrays".

Answer (score 0):

```
$ar=array(array("A","A1"),array("B","B1"))
$ar[]=array("C","C1"); // Append an item

print_r($ar[0]);  // debug purpose

$ar[]=$ar;

print_r($ar);
```